# OpenCV crashing at resize function

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I'm getting a crash inside an iPhone app which is using some OpenCV code. The exception is thrown at the following line:

```
cv::Mat backup_f = m_color_feature;
cv::Mat backup_t = m_map;
double r = m_options.m_opt_height / m_color_feature.rows;
```

**cv::resize(m_color_feature, m_color_feature, cv::Size(), r,r);**
                                                                                                    `cv::resize(m_map, m_map, cv::Size(), r, r);`

I don't have any idea what could be wrong. There are no logs, stack functions or exceptions thrown in XCode that could help me figure out what is going on. It just crashed there...

This are the images from XCode:

[image]
[image]

I tried some modifications to see if it's a memory problem but don't seems the case.

```
    cv::Mat backup_f = m_color_feature;
cv::Mat backup_t = m_map;
double r = m_options.m_opt_height / m_color_feature.rows;
cv::Mat resizedColor = cv::Mat(m_color_feature.rows,m_color_feature.cols,m_color_feature.type());
cv::Mat newTest = cv::Mat(m_color_feature.rows,m_color_feature.cols,m_color_feature.type());
cv::resize(resizedColor, newTest, cv::Size(), r,r);
cv::resize(m_map, m_map, cv::Size(), r, r);
```

If anybody knows of something that could guide me to the solution it would be great. I'm sorry but I got no idea of OpenCV and little experience with C++.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV resize is not an "in place" operator

Try something like this:

```
cv::Mat temp;
cv::Size newDim(...);
cv::resize(m_color_feature, temp, newDim);
m_color_feature = temp.clone();
```

Comment: Ok I tried it, but still got the exception. Could it be that OpenCV is not being linked correctly?

Comment: I can't see any other mistake in your original code, it could surely be a linking problem

Comment: Yes, it was a linking problem as suspected. I had static libs that probably were created against different architecture/compiler.